# Dynamic variable from function in Python

Tags: python

var 1 is constantly changing with every new line that is written in the csv file. Any suggestion how can I get the value outside of the function. This example does not work for me.
I updated my code and added second function which is exactly the same but is reading another file. Now I only get print from the first function only. If I disable the first function I can get the print from the second function. Is there a way to print both of them or maybe three or four if I add later new functions ?

```
import sys
import time
import datetime
import os


class Application():

    def loop_one(self):

       filename = 'Test.csv'
       mycsv = open(filename, 'r')
       mycsv.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

       while 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            where = mycsv.tell()
            line = mycsv.readline()

       if not line:
            mycsv.seek(where)

       else:
           arr_line = line.split(',')
           var1 = arr_line[5]
           mydate = datetime.datetime.now()
           print var1, mydate.strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f")
           return var1

    def loop_two(self):

       filename2 = 'Test2.csv'
       mycsv2 = open(filename2, 'r')
       mycsv2.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

       while 1:
            time2.sleep(1)
            where2 = mycsv2.tell()
            line2 = mycsv2.readline()

       if not line2:
            mycsv2.seek(where2)

       else:
           arr_line2 = line2.split(',')
           var2 = arr_line2[5]
           mydate2 = datetime.datetime.now()
           print var2, mydate.strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f")
           return var2

s = Application()
var1 = s.loop_one()
var2 = s.loop_two()
```

Comment: Have you tried saving a reference? `var1 = s.loop_one()`

Comment: I tried var1 = s.loop_one() and then print var1 but got nothing

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct? Should your `if` and `else` statement be within the `while` loop?

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a variable inside the **init** function so you can use that anywhere

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'Hello'

    def method_a(self, foo):
        print self.x + ' ' + foo
```

In your case you can do something like this (not tested)

```
class Application():

    def __init__(self):

       self.filename = 'Test.csv'
       self.mycsv = open(self.filename, 'r')
       self.mycsv.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
       self.var1 = ''

    def loop_one(self):
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            where = self.mycsv.tell()
            line = self.mycsv.readline()

            if not line:
                self.mycsv.seek(where)
                # you need a break here or somewhere :D

            else:
                arr_line = line.split(',')
                self.var1 = arr_line[5]
                mydate = datetime.datetime.now()
                print self.var1, mydate.strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f")
                return self.var1

s = Application()
s.loop_one()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have move your if else block inside the for loop otherwise your code will stuck in infinite loop.

```
import sys
import time
import datetime
import os

class Application():

    def loop_one(self):

       filename = 'Test.csv'
       mycsv = open(filename, 'r')
       mycsv.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

       while 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            where = mycsv.tell()
            line = mycsv.readline()

            if not line:
                 mycsv.seek(where)

            else:
                arr_line = line.split(',')
                var1 = arr_line[5]
                mydate = datetime.datetime.now()
                print var1, mydate.strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f")
                return var1

s = Application()
s.loop_one()
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `var1` outside the function

```
class Application:
    var1 = None

    def loop_one(self):
        # Code
        while True:
            # Your code
            if not line:
                # Code
            else:
                global var1
                # Code
                var1 = arr_line[5]

    # Then you can access it via
    def show():
        print(var1)
```